# Python Matrix Multiplication '<' not supported between different datatypes

Tags: python, pandas, matrix-multiplication

I am using Python, and would like to get a calculated number **(price * ratio)** from two data frames for each group:

**Table 1:** `df1`

| Group | Category | price_1 | price_2 | price_3 | price_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Single | 20.1 | 19.8 | 19.7 | 19.9 |
| a | Multi | 25.1 | 26.8 | 24.7 | 24.9 |
| b | Multi | 27.1 | 27.8 | 27.7 | 26.9 |

**Table 2:** `df2`

| Group | Category | ratio_1 | ratio_2 | ratio_3 | ratio_4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | Single | 1.0 | 0.8 | 0.7 | 0.5 |
| a | Multi | 1.0 | 0.7 | 0.6 | 0.4 |
| b | Multi | 1.0 | 0.7 | 0.5 | 0.3 |

**Desired Output:** `df`

| Group | Category | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | Single | 59.68 |
| a | Multi | 68.64 |
| b | Multi | 68.48 |

Example, for Group = 'b' and Category = 'Multi', value = 27.1 * 1.0 + 27.8 * 0.7 + 27.7 * 0.5 + 26.9 * 0.3 = 68.48

Input tables: 'Group' and 'Category' in `df1` and `df2` are 'string' data type; the rest columns like 'ratio_1' & 'price_1' are 'float' data type.

Output table: 'Group' and 'Category' are 'string' data type and 'value' is 'float' data type.

With the following code that someone has helped in another thread:

```
idx_cols = ['Group', 'Category']
df1 = df1.set_index(idx_cols)
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)
df2 = df2.set_index(idx_cols)
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.rsplit('_', n=1, expand=True)

df = df1['price'].mul(df2['ratio']).sum(axis=1).reset_index(name="value")
```

Updates: As advised, I've changed the datatypes for `df1` and `df2` all as 'object' but I got the following full error messages:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in safe_sort(values, codes, na_sentinel, assume_unique, verify)
   2014         try:
-> 2015             sorter = values.argsort()
   2016             ordered = values.take(sorter)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-363-e5c47716d89d> in <module>
      8 
      9 # Compute DF3
---> 10 ltv_output = df1['price'].mul(df2['ratio']).sum(axis=1).reset_index(name="ltv_value")

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in f(self, other, axis, level, fill_value)
    764             pass_op = pass_op if not is_logical else op
    765 
--> 766             left, right = self.align(other, join="outer", level=level, copy=False)
    767             new_data = left._combine_frame(right, pass_op, fill_value)
    768             return left._construct_result(new_data)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in align(self, other, join, axis, level, copy, fill_value, method, limit, fill_axis, broadcast_axis)
   3822         broadcast_axis=None,
   3823     ) -> "DataFrame":
-> 3824         return super().align(
   3825             other,
   3826             join=join,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in align(self, other, join, axis, level, copy, fill_value, method, limit, fill_axis, broadcast_axis)
   8463             axis = self._get_axis_number(axis)
   8464         if isinstance(other, ABCDataFrame):
-> 8465             return self._align_frame(
   8466                 other,
   8467                 join=join,

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in _align_frame(self, other, join, axis, level, copy, fill_value, method, limit, fill_axis)
   8510         if axis is None or axis == 0:
   8511             if not self.index.equals(other.index):
-> 8512                 join_index, ilidx, iridx = self.index.join(
   8513                     other.index, how=join, level=level, return_indexers=True
   8514                 )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in join(self, other, how, level, return_indexers, sort)
   3308                 )
   3309             else:
-> 3310                 return self._join_non_unique(
   3311                     other, how=how, return_indexers=return_indexers
   3312                 )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _join_non_unique(self, other, how, return_indexers)
   3426         from pandas.core.reshape.merge import _get_join_indexers
   3427 
-> 3428         left_idx, right_idx = _get_join_indexers(
   3429             [self._ndarray_values], [other._ndarray_values], how=how, sort=True
   3430         )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _get_join_indexers(left_keys, right_keys, sort, how, **kwargs)
   1309         for n in range(len(left_keys))
   1310     )
-> 1311     zipped = zip(*mapped)
   1312     llab, rlab, shape = [list(x) for x in zipped]
   1313 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in <genexpr>(.0)
   1306     # get left & right join labels and num. of levels at each location
   1307     mapped = (
-> 1308         _factorize_keys(left_keys[n], right_keys[n], sort=sort)
   1309         for n in range(len(left_keys))
   1310     )

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _factorize_keys(lk, rk, sort)
   1922     if sort:
   1923         uniques = rizer.uniques.to_array()
-> 1924         llab, rlab = _sort_labels(uniques, llab, rlab)
   1925 
   1926     # NA group

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/merge.py in _sort_labels(uniques, left, right)
   1948     labels = np.concatenate([left, right])
   1949 
-> 1950     _, new_labels = algos.safe_sort(uniques, labels, na_sentinel=-1)
   1951     new_labels = ensure_int64(new_labels)
   1952     new_left, new_right = new_labels[:llength], new_labels[llength:]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in safe_sort(values, codes, na_sentinel, assume_unique, verify)
   2017         except TypeError:
   2018             # try this anyway
-> 2019             ordered = sort_mixed(values)
   2020 
   2021     # codes:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/algorithms.py in sort_mixed(values)
   2000         # order ints before strings, safe in py3
   2001         str_pos = np.array([isinstance(x, str) for x in values], dtype=bool)
-> 2002         nums = np.sort(values[~str_pos])
   2003         strs = np.sort(values[str_pos])
   2004         return np.concatenate([nums, np.asarray(strs, dtype=object)])

<__array_function__ internals> in sort(*args, **kwargs)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py in sort(a, axis, kind, order)
    987     else:
    988         a = asanyarray(a).copy(order="K")
--> 989     a.sort(axis=axis, kind=kind, order=order)
    990     return a
    991 

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Anything I've missed I imagine?

Comment: check the dtypes by `df.dtypes` and notice either `'price'` or ''ratio'' is of dtype object

Comment: @AnuragDabas thanks, should they all be 'object' so that can work?

Comment: you are multiplying so `df1['price'].mul(df2['ratio'])` so for this both the values('price' and 'ratio') have either `float` dtype or `int` dtype......If it doesn't work then please post full traceback of error

Comment: Tried that with df1 and df2 have all fields as 'object' now. But got the same error, I've pasted the full error message as you suggested. In the meantime, will think about maybe original code shall not work, and need to think about sth else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `set_index()` and `split()` method so let's start from beginning(initial phase of your both df's)

try via `merge()` and join both dataframes on 'Group' and 'Category' then multiplying both 'price' and 'ratio' by selecting them using `filter()` method and calculate sum by using `sum()` method and then finally remove those columns(which are used in multiplication) by using `drop()` method:

```
out=df1.merge(df2,on=['Group','Category'])
out['value']=pd.DataFrame(out.filter(like='price').values*out.filter(like='ratio').values).sum(axis=1)
out=out.drop(out.filter(regex='price|ratio').columns,1)
```

output of `out`:

```
  Group     Category    value
0   a       Single      59.68
1   a       Multi       68.64
2   b       Multi       68.48
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried that you suggested, and 'price' and 'ratio' are 'float' now; but it returned something similar: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: @CrubalChenxiLi updated answer...kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: Oh I see that's clear and works as expected. Thanks!